# Does error in JSONP responce body stop browser JS engine?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

If browser load HTML page with JS scripts (by **script** tag) and syntax error occured during parsing of JS browser stop evaluating of any other JS.

Does error in JSONP responce body also stop JS engine (I afraid that one invalid JSONP response stops any other subsequent valid JSONP responses)?

Note that content of remote JSONP response usually doesn't controlled by original site...